# auth.log errors: kex_exchange_identification: banner line contains invalid characters

Tags: ssh, ubuntu-16.04

I have the auth log with thousands of:

```
error: kex_exchange_identification: banner line contains invalid characters
```

I can't find which process is causing this. How can I troubleshoot it?

Using: Ubuntu 16.04 OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.9, OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020

Comment: This is probably caused by ssh. Check your /etc/ssh/sshd_config. Maybe also install and configure fail2ban to prevent SSH attacks.